# How do I change the "NativeHost" string on Windows Phone 7 webclient requests

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient

I use WebClient for most of my requests from my WP7 app. 
According to Google App Engine logs, the UserAgent is "NativeHost". 
I would like to use appname, appversion + phone instead.

Is it possible to change this string when using a WebClient, or a GZip WebClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, current working solution:

```
var headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
// http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.fi/2011/03/easy-access-to-wmappmanifestxml-app.html
var am = new Util.AppManifest(); // gets appmanifest as per link above
var maker = Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer;
var model = Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName;

 headers["user-agent"] = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} AppVersion {3}",
                                       maker, model, "WP7.5", am.Version);

WebClient c = new WebClient();
c.Headers = headers;
```

Now, let's see how much info I can get on what make of phone the app is running on...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to manually specify the UserAgent string on the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();

client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "My App; V=2.1, PhoneType");
```

Obviously you will need to specify/derive the values you want to use in the UserAgent (AppName, Version and Phone).

Comment: Close. Except you can't add to headers like that. But, put me on right track, thanks.

Comment: client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "My App; V=2.1, PhoneType"); works in ASP.net. In WP7 we have to add like this headers["user-agent"] = "user-agesnt string";